# WPF datagrid filter with checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a datagrid in WPF with the columns first name, last name, hours, and grade. I want to filter it with checkboxes to only show the something like people with >200 hours, or only people in 9th grade. I want it to be dynamic so you can check and uncheck the checkbox and the datagrid would dynamically filter for all the checked ones. For example, only those in 9th and 10th grade with <100 hours would be 3 checkboxes, the 9th grade, 10th grade, and the <100 hours filter all applied to the Datagrid. Can someone help, I haven't been able to find what i'm looking for.

```
 class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Grade { get; set; }
        public double Hours { get; set; }
    }

List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
```

Then in wpf, I have a simple datagrid where I make the `TestDatagrid.itemsource= people` and I want to filter the datagrid programmatically with a set of checkboxes.

Comment: Please, share your code and xaml markup

Answer (score 0):

What about LINQ?
like Checkbox.IsChecked
TestDatagrid.itemsource = people.Where(p => p.Grade > 100).Select(p =>p);
May be the syntax is wrong - I have not installed VisualStudio on this computer.

Comment: Thank you, this is a step in the right direction. Now how would I make a LINQ for multiple conditions that have to be checked (which checkbox is checked) and have it make the appropriate list? for example, a list of both 9th and 10th graders that also have more than 200 hours?

Comment: Sorry, I am on business trip now and answering via my phone only. Of course, you can chain LINQ queries like sql.